# Is there a way to create a script that go and find the same username in another workbook and then take the information in the adjacent cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My problem is that I would like to modify my existing script in appscript in order that no emailaddress is imported in the mailroom tracker. So what I would like the script to do is that when I run the email sending button:

- the script go seach for the same recipient name in the other workbook (other google sheet) and then take the corresponding email address in the next cell on the right
- When it has it store it temporarly in an array
- use it and then delete the table
- The document containing the email should not be open on the computer but virtualy

Here is an example of the sheet and script I would like to modify (the url are all accessible) :

- mailroon tracker : "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ub8m4mHscHuOhuDxNHJI5XTrNPqd2qNdBCjeansUI8/edit?usp=sharing"
- List of people and email address: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels/edit?usp=sharing"
- List item

If you could help me with it and explain me in big lines what you did that would help me so much !!

Kind regards,
Constantin

Here is what I did :

```
// you need to activate the script, give authorization, and put a triiger on onSpeEdit once
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('** ACTIVATION **')
  .addItem(' Activate', 'activate')
  .addToUi();
}
function activate(){
  if(!isTrigger('onSpeEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSpeEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onEdit()
      .create();
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('your script is now active !')
}

// main function
function onSpeEdit(event) {
  var ws = event.source.getActiveSheet()
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange()
  if (cel.getValue()){
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels')
    var mails = wb.getSheetByName('On site')
    var data = mails.getDataRange().getValues()
    var recipientName = ws.getRange(cel.getRow(),4).getValue()
    var emailAddress = ''
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][1] == recipientName){
        emailAddress = data[i][2]
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(recipientName + ' ' + emailAddress)

    // ############### send email here ###############
function sendEmails() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var Date = row[0];
    var Tracking = row[1];
    var Carrier = row[2];
    var Recepient = row [4]
    var Business = row[5];
    var EmailSent = row[8].trim();
    var PickedUp = row [9]
    var Reminder = row[10];

    if (Tracking !="" && EmailSent!="X" && PickedUp=="") {
    Logger.log("IncomingDate="+Tracking +" Sent to ="+ emailAddress);
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        emailAddress+"gmail.com", 
        "Your Parcel from "+Carrier+ " has been delivered today", 
        "Hi "+Recepient+",\n\n"+
        "I hope you are having a great day so far.\n\nI just received a parcel for you delivered by "+Carrier+" with tracking number "+TrackingNumber+". As from now, you can pick it up from the B-BRU office mailroom on the 3rd floor from Monday till Friday between 8:30am-5pm.\n \nShould you have any other questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are always happy to help you!:) \n\n"+
        "Best regards,\n\n"+
        
        "The B-BRU Reception team \n\n\n");
      }
      sheet.getRange("F"+(parseInt(i)+2).toString()).setValue("X");
    }
      

  }
}

// trigger management
function myTriggerSetup(nom) {
  if(!isTrigger(nom)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(nom)
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();  
  }
}
function myTriggerDelete(nom){
     deleteTriggersByName(nom);
}
function deleteTriggersByName(name){
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++){ 
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction().indexOf(name) != -1) 
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
}}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
     var r=false;
     if(funcName) {
       var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
       var allHandlers=[];
       for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) {
         allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
       }
       if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1) {
         r=true;
       }
     }
 } return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the informations by using

```
function myFunction() {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels')
  var ws = wb.getSheetByName('On site')
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

### reference

[openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

### edit

your complete script:

```
// main function
function onSpeEdit(event) {
  var ws = event.source.getActiveSheet()
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange()
  if (cel.getValue()){
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels')
    var mails = wb.getSheetByName('On site')
    var data = mails.getDataRange().getValues()
    var recipientName = ws.getRange(cel.getRow(),4).getValue()
    var emailAddress = ''
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][1] == recipientName){
        emailAddress = data[i][2]
      }
    }

    var row=ws.getRange(cel.getRow(),1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()
    var Date = row[0][0];
    var Tracking = row[0][1];
    var Carrier = row[0][2];
    var Recepient = row[0][3]
    var Business = row[0][4];
    var EmailSent = row[0][5].trim();
    var PickedUp = row[0][6];
    var Reminder = row[0][7];

    if (Tracking !="" && EmailSent!="X" && PickedUp=="") {
      
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress+"@gmail.com",
        subject: "Your Parcel from "+Carrier+ " has been delivered today", 
        htmlBody: "Hi "+Recepient+",<br><br>I hope you are having a great day so far.<br><br>I just received a parcel for you delivered by "+Carrier+" with tracking number "+Tracking+". As from now, you can pick it up from the B-BRU office mailroom on the 3rd floor from Monday till Friday between 8:30am-5pm.<br> <br>Should you have any other questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are always happy to help you!:) <br><br>Best regards,<br><br>The B-BRU Reception team <br><br><br>"
      })

      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("IncomingDate = "+Tracking +" Sent to ="+ emailAddress);
    }
    ws.getRange("F"+cel.getRow()).setValue("X");

  }
}
```

- first you will have to activate the script, give authorization, and put a trigger on onSpeEdit function
- then check one box
- I have added somme extra function for trigger management

### edit2

If you want to do the same with a button

```
function sendEmails() {
var ws =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
for (var ligne=1;ligne<=ws.getLastDataRow('A');ligne++){

  if (ws.getRange('E'+ligne).getValue() && ws.getRange("F"+ligne).getValue()==''){

    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels')
    var mails = wb.getSheetByName('On site')
    var data = mails.getDataRange().getValues()
    var recipientName = ws.getRange(ligne,8).getValue()
    var emailAddress = ''
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][1] == recipientName){
        emailAddress = data[i][2]
      }
    }

    var row=ws.getRange(ligne,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()
    var Date = row[0][0];
    var Tracking = row[0][1];
    var Carrier = row[0][2];
    var Recepient = row[0][3]
    var Business = row[0][4];
    var EmailSent = row[0][5].trim();
    var PickedUp = row[0][6];
    var Reminder = row[0][7];
    var SendEmail = row[0][8]

    if (Tracking !="" && EmailSent!="X" && PickedUp=="") {
      
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress+"@gmail.com",
        subject: "Your Parcel from "+Carrier+ " has been delivered today", 
        htmlBody: "Hi "+Recepient+",<br><br>I hope you are having a great day so far.<br><br>I just received a parcel for you delivered by "+Carrier+" with tracking number "+Tracking+". As from now, you can pick it up from the B-BRU office mailroom on the 3rd floor from Monday till Friday between 8:30am-5pm.<br> <br>Should you have any other questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are always happy to help you!:) <br><br>Best regards,<br><br>The B-BRU Reception team <br><br><br>"
      })

      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("IncomingDate = "+Tracking +" Sent to ="+ emailAddress);
    }
    ws.getRange("F"+ligne).setValue("X");

  }

}
}

Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for your fast response - I really appreaciated !! I just had more question. How would you adapt the formula so that: the script find the coresponding name in the virtual data, store it temporarly in a variable "RecipientName" and send an email to it with the informations contained in the line of the coresponding name .  It will then do the same for the next name of the list. I`am stuck here :  I have added the script in the sheet ( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ub8m4mHscHuOhuDxNHJI5XTrNPqd2qNdBCjeansUI8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: you have already accepted the other answer, so I leave you with vector, sincerely yours ...

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for trying to help me. If by any chance you have another way to do it feel free to do so. I am learning so I am interested in as many possibility as possible. Best wishes, Constantin

Comment: No worries! Thank you so much for taking the time Mike!

Comment: I would suggest you to replace the button by checking in a box. So that the email will be sent as soon as a box is checked without having to press the button. Is that acceptable for you ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I did not think about triggers.

Comment: Hi Mike, wow you went above and beyond - thank you!! I just had one last question I have adapted my script but no email was sent to the recipient. ( i have adapted the script above to show what i did)

Comment: I have included and adapted your script ... see my updated answer

Comment: Hi Mike, I just test it. Thank so much for your  help! I am so grateful for your help and the learning opportunity!!  I wish you a happy New Year in advance! Thanks, Constantin

Comment: You are welcome! Happy New Year for you and your family too.

Comment: Hi Mike, me again. I just wanted to ask if you could show me how to do the same thing but with the buttons this time and not the triggers ? Best wishes, Constantin

Comment: done (see edit2)

Comment: Thank you so much Mike! I wish you an excellent day further!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **openById()** or **openByURL ** method to extract data from that email sheet.

```js
function extractEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ag6RMAITxpEEG6D7kGArBv4EbH3cRdT8nUPkyYhfels')//This will access your spreadsheet "virtually" 
  var ssname = wb.getSheetByName('Employee_Email_SheetName')//This will access the following sheet in that spreadsheet, make sure to use proper sheet name
  var emailData = ws.getDataRange().getValues() // this will get the data from that sheet
  return emailData
}
```

Suppose you just need emails from specific column from that sheet, ex: C1:C20 has your emails information, than in that case you can replace

```
ws.getDataRange().getValues()
```

with

```
ws.getRange('C1:C20').getValues() //C1:C20 is your email range
```

**Reference:**

[openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

[openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

Comment: Thanks Vector for your fast response - I really appreaciated !! I just had more question. How would you adapt the formula so that: the script find the coresponding name in the virtual data, store it temporarly in a variable "RecipientName" and send an email to it with the informations contained in the line of the coresponding name .  It will then do the same for the next name of the list. I`am stuck here :  I have added the script in the sheet ( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ub8m4mHscHuOhuDxNHJI5XTrNPqd2qNdBCjeansUI8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, some followup questions in response to your next problem, You want to select the checkbox in that shared sheet and want the script to look for email of the Recipient in that selected row, and send email back to it with the information available in that row? Is that right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want the script to take the name of the the recipient I just enter the information. Then I want the script to find the same name in the virtual data and match it with the corresponding email address ( the cell next to it). Then the script will finaly put the result in the variable "EmailAddress". Then hopefully the rest of my send emailscript will do the rest and re-iterate the script for the next line.

Comment: AlsoThe check box is just there to indicate if the parcel is business related or not. I want the script to the same for every line individualy meaning that each recipient will receive an email with their own parcel information.